# asp.net delete item from gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

im using asp.net and sql server . i have a gridview in my asp form which is binded in my form load . i wrote a command on my delete button but it doesn't effect . 
here is my code :

ASP.net :

```
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#" ItemStyle-CssClass="Company_Grid_Checkbox">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldCountPhoto" HeaderText="تعداد عکس" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldActive" HeaderText="موقعیت نمایش" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldPrice" HeaderText="قیمت" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldYear" HeaderText="سال" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldModel" HeaderText="مدل" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldCompany" HeaderText="کمپانی" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="fldTbl_UserCarID" HeaderText="ID" />
                        </Columns>
```

C# code :

```
    protected void btn_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label1.Text = (i++).ToString();
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {

                    string id = row.Cells[7].Text;
                    Label1.Text = "id";

                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString);

                    string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM tbl_Usercar WHERE fldTbl_UserCarID = @fldTbl_UserCarID";

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fldTbl_UserCarID", id);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
```

in the above codes i wrote only the part of gridview and i didnt write other parts .

Comment: Debug your code step by step and find what is the real issue. The `but it doesn't effect` give no informations about your error, and if the error is a logic mistake on your code ?

Comment: i did but in if (chkRow.Checked) part i dont get any test result . can you help me which do i have any mistake here ?

Comment: Really if I could I help, but I do not understand the issue and can not do debug on my mind (on this case)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are binding the grid in Page_Load without checking for IsPostBack. This would cause your grid to rebind before your button click event, which resets your checkboxes.